# How to make each current element in loop centered in container

Tags: javascript, html, css

1. As the container slides to the left, I want each tab to be centered for a brief moment in the container.
2. Before the animation begins, I want the very first tab to be centered in the container on page load before the animation begins. I know I need to divide each element's `offsetWidth` by 2 so that it is calculated to be centered but I'm not sure where/how to do that.

Link to JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nb5a92x3/

```js
window.onload = function() {
    
    const tabsContainer = document.querySelector('.tabsContainer');
    const tabs = tabsContainer.querySelectorAll('.tab');

    function animate(target) {
        let siblings = [];
        let elm = target;
        let keyframes = [];
        let offset;
    
        // Push the widths of each previous element to an array
        while (elm = elm.previousElementSibling) {
            siblings.push(elm.offsetWidth);
        }
        
        // Add the sum of all previous elements
        offset = siblings.reduce((prev, current) => prev + current, 0);

        // Animate the container to the left
        setTimeout(function() {
            tabsContainer.style.left = `calc(50% - ${offset}px)`;
        }, i * 800);
    }
    
    // Run the code
    for (i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
        animate(tabs[i]);
    }
  }
```

```css
body {
    background: #ccc;
}

section {
    text-align: center;
    width: 375px;
    background: white;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 16px;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.tabsContainer {
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    gap: 0 16px;
    transition: left 0.2s ease;

    .tab {
        border-radius: 25px;
        background: gray;
        text-align: center;
        height: 34px;
        display: inline-flex;
        align-items: center;
        padding: 0 16px;
    }
}
```

```html
<section>
  <ul class="tabsContainer">
    <li class="tab">TAB ONE</li>
    <li class="tab">ANOTHER TAB HERE</li>
    <li class="tab">A REALLY LONG TAB HERE</li>
    <li class="tab">LAST TAB</li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set in CSS your container to `margin-left: 50%`
than all you need is `x = EL_curr.offsetLeft + EL_curr.offsetWidth / 2`
and apply that `x` value to the slider-container CSS **translateX** (which is far more performant than animating the CSS `left` property, since `transform` can be [hardware](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Performance/Fundamentals) [accelerated](https://www.paulirish.com/2012/why-moving-elements-with-translate-is-better-than-posabs-topleft/)).

```js
// Utility functions:

const EL  = (sel, par) => (par || document).querySelector(sel);
const ELS = (sel, par) => (par || document).querySelectorAll(sel);

// Tabs animator:

const tabsAnimator = (EL_slider) => {
  const ELS_items = ELS(".tab", EL_slider);
  const tot = ELS_items.length;
  let curr = 0;
  let tOut;

  const anim = () => {
    const EL_curr = ELS_items[curr];
    const x = EL_curr.offsetLeft + EL_curr.offsetWidth / 2;
    EL_slider.style.transform = `translateX(-${x}px)`;
    curr += 1; // Increment counter
    if (curr > tot - 1) curr = 0; // Reset counter
    tOut = setTimeout(anim, 1500);
  };

  anim(); // Init!
};

ELS(".tabsContainer").forEach(tabsAnimator);
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.tabsWrapper {
  width: 375px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  padding: 16px 0;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #ccc;
  border-radius: 3em;
}

.tabsContainer {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  display: inline-flex;
  list-style: none;
  gap: 0 15px;
  transition: transform 0.3s;
  margin-left: 50%;
}

.tabsContainer .tab {
  border-radius: 25px;
  background: gold;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 5px 15px;
}
```

```html
<section class="tabsWrapper">
  <ul class="tabsContainer">
    <li class="tab">5 OFF FRIDAY</li>
    <li class="tab">10 OFFSUMMER</li>
    <li class="tab">SAVE MORE</li>
    <li class="tab">HALF OFF EVERYTHING</li>
  </ul>
</section>

<section class="tabsWrapper">
  <ul class="tabsContainer">
    <li class="tab">JavaScript</li>
    <li class="tab">HTML</li>
    <li class="tab">CSS</li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

- don't use horizontal paddings on the wrapper or container slider.
- don't *just* use `section` as a selector. It's too common. Use rather a specific class like `.tabsWrapper` on the wrapper parent.

Additionally, if you'd like to **pause the animation** on `"mouseenter"`, use `clearTimeout(tOut);` — and just `anim()` in the `"mouseleave"` Event.

Comment: This works great, thanks! How would I fix this so that it only runs once instead of looping?

Comment: Instead of using `curr = 0;` exit the function using `return;`

Comment: @shawnkauffman Just out of curiosity... what are you building? What is this UI use-case?